# Handing image file not found error in Django

Tags: django, image, http-status-code-404, url-pattern

I am trying to handle the image not found an error in Django by defining a custom view `unhandle_urls`.
The way I am trying to do this is the following.

*Define a URL pattern inside `urls.py` to match the image URL's pattern and route them to my custom view  `unhandle_urls`*

Here are my url patterns inside `urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [

        ....

        path(r'images/*', unhandle_urls, name="handling image not found urls"),

        ...

]
```

However, I am still getting the same 404 error whenever any image is requested.
Here is the error msg:

```
GET https:my-website-base-url/images/searchbox/desktop_searchbox_sprites318_hr.png 404 (Not Found)
```

I am not sure what the problem is. My guess is that the url pattern `r'images/*'` is not matching to
`https:my-website-base-url/images/searchbox/desktop_searchbox_sprites318_hr.png`, but when I try to look at this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/, I could not find what's wrong with my regex or my approach.

Any type of help/suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

## Update:

Here is my view

```py
def unhandle_urls(request):
    if is_authenticated(request):
        return HttpResponse('')
    else:
        return render(request, "error.html", {})
```

Comment: Please show your view

Comment: I have added the view. However, the URL call is not routed to the view.

Comment: I think you want to use `re_path` instead.